# Powershell get email content by date

Tags: powershell, date, email, filter, directory

I found the scripts below can get the e-mail content by powershell:

```
Add-Type -Assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook"
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$namespace = $Outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
$inbox = $namespace.GetDefaultFolder([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders]::olFolderRssFeeds)
$inbox.Items | Format-Table SenderName, To, CC, ReceivedTime,  Subject, Body
```

1. But how to filter by date. Like hope to get Today's e-mail? (Frequency should be 1 day or half day)
2. How to filter by Subject?
3. For the [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders]::olFolderRssFeeds), Is it ok to change the default folder to the folder created by ourselves?

Comment: What have you tried? Ideally you should also avoid asking multiple questions at once.

Answer (score 0):

For Q1 and Q2, can use where-object to filter the answer:

Filter the content:| where-object { $_.Subject -ilike "*Errors*"}

Filter the date: | where-object { $_.ReceivedTime -gt "$date"}

For Q3, still cannot find the answer

Answer (score 0):

For your Q3 you can use the below command to get the mails from specific folder

```
$Namespace.Folders.Item(1).Folders.Item('your folder name').Items
```